# sending email to office 365 email using smtp

Tags: email, office365, laravel-9

I have a contact form built with Laravel, and I want to send an email to my company email which is hosted from office 365 and my website hosting is Cloudflare

this is the env file configuration

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com
```

when I send an email using a contact form the email never receives to company email and when I try another receiver like yahoo or Gmail the message is delivered fine.
do any one know why i can't receive emails in my company email.
I have tried mailtrap testing and every thing was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, Cloudflare needs to add records to the domain to be authenticated by office 365
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/need-help-with-office-365-error/80501/4